# Measuring the time of eating (c'dei achilas pras)

Tags: sources-mekorot, passover, shiurim-measurements, matzah

I once saw written in a "alon" (given out in shuls before Shabbos) that in regards to eating matzah that it has to be done in the amount of time that is "c'dei achilas pras" -- that this time begins to be counted not from when the food (matzah) enters ones mouth, but rather from the time the person begins to swallow the matzah. The author who wrote this did not mention any source and simply stating that that is the halacha.

What is the source for this? Is it accepted by all poskim or are there those that argue on this? If so, who? Sources?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/70183/759 I don't see why you'd think anything but swallowing is relevant. It's the only relevant action of eating for Mitzvot/Lavim that I can think of. If you chew pork and spit it out then nothing happened.

Comment: @DoubleAA Rav Wosner seems to hold that chewing might be enough to start the shiur: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1419&pgnum=166 (Ois hei)

Comment: ״אכלן לחצאין יצא ובלבד שלא ישהא בין אכילה לחבירתה יותר מכדי אכילת פרס״ is the Gemara. It's a pause between two specific activities. If chewing is eating then you must hold that you can keep chewing for an hour in between swallows since you've never paused. The simpler position is that swallowing is eating while chewing is effectively pausing.

Comment: @DoubleAA that's a good question. Look at Siman 475 Mishnah Brurah Sif-Katan 40, 41, 42. Why does it seem from 40 and 42 that the shiur starts from when it goes in your mouth? וה"ה אפילו לא הפסיק בינתים אלא ששהה באכילתו את הכזית יותר מכדי אכילת פרס אין מצטרף יחד ואינו יוצא